# Style from CSS class is not applied to the div with respective class

Tags: html, css, electron, css-grid

What is the reason that the CSS class style is not applied to the div with the class `content__ticket`, but the style of the class `content__ticket__title` is applied?

```css
.content__ticket {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 96px) minmax(0, 38px) minmax(0, 296px) repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 'title title title title' 'instruction instruction instruction instruction' '. qr-code qr-code .' '. . . .' 'mail-button mail-button finish-button finish-button' '. . . .';
  grid-gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content__ticket__title {
  grid-area: title;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content__ticket">
  <div class="content__ticket__title block center">
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

[image: Applied styles of content__ticket]

[image: Applied styles of content__ticket__title]

This style is in the same file as the style for content__ticket__title.

#### What did I try to fix it:

1. I tried to rename the class to a cryptic name, that 100% wouldn't be used somewhere else.
2. I tried making the CSS for specific with `div.content__ticket`

I am working on Electron Version: 9.0.3

Comment: I see both classes' styles being applied in the demo above.

Comment: Maybe you have browser caching, and the one class isn't in the stylesheet that's being used.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, that is the parent div picks up its class and sets up a grid and the child element takes up the 4 columns that constitute the title area. What is it that you think ought to be happening that isn't happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself after tons of investigations I made the simplest mistake...

I had an empty css block over this one, but I didn't open or close {}.

So what happend it searched for a .content__ticket as a child of some other class:

```
.some_other_class
/* Ticket */

.content__ticket {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 96px) minmax(0, 38px) minmax(0, 296px) repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 'title title title title' 'instruction instruction instruction instruction' '. qr-code qr-code .' '. . . .' 'mail-button mail-button finish-button finish-button' '. . . .';
    grid-gap: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Simple but anoying misstake...